# Android Eclipse - package folder not "normal" in src folder

Tags: android, eclipse

Someone please fix my title. This problem is so weird that I have no idea what to call it.

Here is what my `src` folder *should*, and usually does, look like in my Package Explorer view:

[image]

Here is what is looks like now:

[image]

I don't remember what I did to do this (Eclipse is the most buggy program I've ever used in my life). I think it might have happened when I was attempting to create a JAR file with my classes.

The problem with this is:

1. My app *always* crashes on startup.
2. I don't have error messages. I could write `iynbiun` in my classes and there would be no red underline. It will always let me run (therefore compile my classes) my app even with uncompilable code.

How can I make it go back to the way it was in the first image?

Comment: Try Right-click on the com.mikeyaworski package, select Refactor... then Rename and rename back to com.mikeyaworski.calculator. Then select all the .java files in that calculator sub-directory, Right-click and select Copy. Then click on the newly renamed com.mikeyaworski.calculator package, right-click and select Paste. Assuming all goes well, delete that spurious calculator sub-directory and all of the contents. Do make sure to make a backup first of course. ;)

Comment: @Squonk I've tried renaming. This is my error: `An exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Rename Package'. Reason: assertion failed: Cannot move '/Calculator/src/com/mikeyaworski/calculator'. Destination should not be under source's hierarchy.`

Comment: From the icon, it looks like the calculator sub-folder is simply a filesystem folder (and not an eclipse 'Source' folder. I'd be tempted to close the project and eclipse then move all the files using WIndows explorer (assuming you're using Windows) into your \src\com\mikeyaworski folder then delete the calculator sub-folder, restart eclipse and open the project and see what happens. I'd recommend doing a Refresh on the project and probably a Clean. You may be able to rename the package then.

Comment: @Squonk I just tried that and once I renamed it, it went back to the way it was (the weird way). I'll keep trying stuff like that though. Something to note: in my windows explorer, all of the .java file types are actually `IntelliJ IDEA Project File (.java)` for some reason. I don't know if that's significant or not.

Comment: Last resort...I'd close eclipse, copy the ANdroidManifest.xml and all the .java files somewhere safe then open eclipse and delete the project completely (including source files). I'd then create a new bare-bones ANdroid project with the same project name and package name, close eclipse then manually copy the files back into place, start eclipse and choose Refresh. BTW, which version of eclipse are you using? I had lots of problems a few years ago but I found Juno to be pretty stable on Windows. I now use Kepler which seems OK.

Comment: One more thing - have you installed Android Studio? The fact your .java files are shown as IntelliJ IDEA files suggest you may have - I tried the first preview of Android Studio and it seriously screwed one of my projects - I haven't touched it since.

Comment: @Squonk I was thinking about starting with a fresh workspace which will suck but that will be my last resort. I'm using Juno right now and it's caused me nothing but problems.And yes I installed Android Studio and I'm going to uninstall it right now.

Answer (score 0):

A little help for you.

Just create a new package named as `com.mikeyaworski.calculator` as it before(make sure same package name is inside *gen* folder).

Then drag the calculator folder from `com.mikeyaworski` to `com.mikeyaworski.calculator`.

I think after this step you just have to rename the package because after dragging of calculator folder the package should be renamed as `com.mikeyaworski.calculator.calculator`.

So just rename it as usual and delete the empty `com.mikeyaworski` package.

As my knowledge if our package name is `com.mikeyaworski.abcd` then all activities are saved inside *com folder ->  mikeyaworski folder -> abcd folder* .

Sometimes due to some changes the package path destroys and all our android related classes becomes plane java files. So if we reconstruct the package path and put all java classes inside this it must be as before.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test this out because I just started a new workspace and copied over my files. Sorry. If it happens again and this works, I'll be sure to let you know.